# Jenkins: sending build emails at different times to different recipients

Tags: email, jenkins

Mel here, I was wondering if there was a way to send email notifications to different recipients at different times using Jenkins.

I currently use Jenkins 1.620 with the Email-Ext plugin to build my project, send an email (containing attachments) to multiple users at a set time.  That's all well and good, but I would then like to run this project again at another time that day, sending that email to another recipient list.  It looks as though I can schedule the build for multiple times during the day, but I can't change the recipients for those varying scheduled builds.

Is there any way through Jenkins, besides creating another build for every time I want to run my project, to send emails to different recipients at different times?

(Just in case its useful, the project's build steps are 1:invoke an ant command to build then 2: execute a windows batch command to run).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Email Pre-send Script](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin#Email-extplugin-Pre-sendScript) to dynamically change a recipient list. For example, here is a groovy script that shows how to prepare your recipient list depending on an hour of the day:

```java
import javax.mail.Message

hour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

if (hour < 9) {
  msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, "rec1@company.com, rec2@company.com")
} else if (hour >= 9 && hour <= 18) {
  msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, "rec3@company.com")
} else {
  msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, "admin@company.com")
}
```

Comment: Great! Do you know if you can use {DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS} instead of listing the emails out in this format?

Comment: @MMM Not sure about using env variables in Pre-send Script, let me check. BTW `msg` variable by default contains a list of recipients specified in Project Recipient List field. So, probably you will not need to use a `DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS`  variable in your script.

Comment: @ Vitalii I ran into this error: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Boolean.call() is applicable for argument types: (Script1$_run_closure1) values: [Script1$_run_closure1@10e4a9c]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), each(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure), and(java.lang.Boolean).  Do you know what this might mean? Thanks for the help!

Comment: That looks strange. Did you just copied and pasted it ?

Comment: So it was something I did, I removed else if and tried a parameter with the else statement (since I was trying to test it with two recipient groups) and that was the error! All me. Thanks for the help and wealth of knowledge.

Comment: Great! I just checked how to use `DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS` in script, seems  this is not possible, this is not even a variable... But all information available in `msg` object.

Answer (score 1):

Create two new projects that trigger your build project parameterized with different recipients settings:

- Add post-build action → Trigger parameterized build on other projects

  - Add parameters → Predefined parameters

    - Parameters: `RECIPIENTS_PASSED_FROM_TRIGGER_PROJECT=<e-mail adresses>`

Configure your build project to be parameterized:

- Meta Data → [✔] This build is parameterized

  - Add Parameter → String Parameter

    - Name: `RECIPIENTS_PASSED_FROM_TRIGGER_PROJECT`

and use this parameter in its:

- Post-build Actions → Editable Email Notification

  - Project Recipient List: `${RECIPIENTS_PASSED_FROM_TRIGGER_PROJECT}`

Comment: This is a great explanation of how to interact with Jenkins to set up parameterization.  This has an added bonus of not having to re-write and setup the build every time I create a new project by triggering the original program.  I was looking to not have to create a new project for every group of recipients, but this makes the process much shorter.